# I have an XSLT where I have 2 different cases and due to multiple item loops I am not getting the desired output

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, edi

In my XSLT I am checking if `oa:ShipUnitQuantity` is less than 1 in that case my output should be `FLOW_856MMO`; when `oa:ShipUnitQuantity` is greater than 1 and `oa:DocumentReference/@type='ManualMarkout'` then my output should be `FLOW_856PARMMO` rest all should go to `FLOW_856NONMMO`.

Due to multiple `us:ShipmentUnit` loops I am not able to get the `FLOW_856PARMMO` output.

My input:

```
<us:ShowShipment releaseID="1.0" systemEnvironmentCode="Production" languageCode="en-US">
    <us:DataArea>
        <oa:Show/>
        <us:Shipment>
            <us:ShipmentHeader>
                <oa:DocumentID>
                    <oa:ID>63210223S000003</oa:ID>
                </oa:DocumentID>
            </us:ShipmentHeader>
            <us:ShipmentOrder>
                <us:ShipmentHeader>
                    <oa:DocumentReference type="OMSOrderInfo">
                        <oa:SalesOrderReference>
                            <oa:DocumentID>
                                <oa:ID>BFDKK7J</oa:ID>
                            </oa:DocumentID>
                            <oa:ReleaseNumber>2</oa:ReleaseNumber>
                        </oa:SalesOrderReference>
                    </oa:DocumentReference>
                    <oa:ShipUnitQuantity>3</oa:ShipUnitQuantity>
                </us:ShipmentHeader>
                <us:ShipmentUnit>
                    <us:ShipCode>Y</us:ShipCode>
                    <us:CODAmount currencyID="USD">0</us:CODAmount>
                    <us:ShipmentUnitItem>
                        <oa:UPCID>00000000000001</oa:UPCID>
                    </us:ShipmentUnitItem>
                    <us:ShipmentUnitItem>
                        <oa:UPCID>00000000000003</oa:UPCID>
                        <oa:DocumentReference type="ManualMarkout">
                            <oa:Status>
                                <oa:Code>MM,24</oa:Code>
                            </oa:Status>
                        </oa:DocumentReference>
                </us:ShipmentUnit>
                <us:ShipmentUnit>
                    <us:ShipCode>Y</us:ShipCode>
                    <us:CODAmount currencyID="USD">0</us:CODAmount>
                    <us:ShipmentUnitItem>
                        <oa:UPCID >00000000000004</oa:UPCID>
                    </us:ShipmentUnitItem>
                </us:ShipmentUnit>
            </us:ShipmentOrder>
        </us:Shipment>
    </us:DataArea>
</us:ShowShipment>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:us='http://www.ussco.com/oagis/0' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:oa='http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9' version="1.0">
    <!-- <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:param name="lineDelimiter" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <!-- -->
    <!--  -->
<!--<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> -->

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:element name="OUTPUT">
  <xsl:element name="Flag_ind">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(/us:ShowShipment/us:DataArea/us:Shipment/us:ShipmentOrder/us:ShipmentHeader/oa:ShipUnitQuantity) &lt; 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="'FLOW_856MMO'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(/us:ShowShipment/us:DataArea/us:Shipment/us:ShipmentOrder/us:ShipmentHeader/oa:ShipUnitQuantity) &gt; 1 and (/us:ShowShipment/us:DataArea/us:Shipment/us:ShipmentOrder/us:ShipmentUnit/us:ShipmentUnitItem/oa:DocumentReference[@type='ManualMarkout'])">
                <xsl:value-of select="'FLOW_856PARMMO'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'FLOW_856NONMMO'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output: This should be `FLOW_856PARMMO` but the logic is hitting the otherwise case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OUTPUT>
    <Flag_ind>FLOW_856NONMMO</Flag_ind>
</OUTPUT>
```

Comment: After I try to make the input source a wellformed document, I cannot reproduce your problem, beside that "greater than" and "lower than" do not partition the logic space. Check it [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4v6)